# Block Access to raspi-config

Tags: raspi-config

I want to let one of my friends use my Raspberry Pi remotely, but I don't want him to have access to raspi-config to change settings. Is there any way to block access to raspi-config or set a separate password??

Comment: You could and probably should create a new user account for him. Without sudo privileges or limited privileges he wont be able to access raspi-config. You may need to grant him sudo privileges if he needs to access the GPIO pins.

Comment: Tweaking `sudo` does need to be done carefully, the recommendation is to use `sudo -e /etc/sudoers` which invokes a consistency check on a temporary edit version, only replacing the real file if it makes sense.  This can help you to avoid locked *yourself* out of the system.  As @SteveRobillard suggests a separate account is really sensible - check out the `adduser` command (needs root privileges) - Unix always was multi-user system from the ground up (unlike certain products from Redmond in the US of A) and remote access by others is well within capabilities of a RPi *nix distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add a new user like Steve said, and revoke `sudo` privileges from that user. Here is a quick tutorial on this:

```
sudo useradd USERNAME
```

Obviously you need to replace `USERNAME` with the name of the user you want. Then, you will need to set a password for that user with:

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

If you do not set a password the user will be locked until you do.
Then, to revoke privileges:

```
sudo deluser USERNAME sudo
```

This will remove the user `USERNAME` from the group `sudo`.

Here are some complete tutorials, just in case:

- [Create New User](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-new-linux-user-account/)
- [Revoke sudo Privileges](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335987/remove-sudo-privileges-from-a-user-without-deleting-the-user)

Comment: Have you actually tried this. Last time I did (a long time ago) you had to specifically add groups to the new user.

Comment: Only if you want that user to be a member of those groups.  There will be a new group added for it automatically (see `man useradd`).